# Tkinter: how to show and hide Frame class

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have something like this:

in the main app class, I have three frame class. And ideally, I would use show_frame to forget all of them and only grid the one I specified.

```
self.frames = {}

for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
    frame = F(container, self)
    self.frames[F] = frame

self.show_frame(StartPage)


def show_frame(self, cont):
    for f in self.frames:
        f.grid_forget(self)

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')
```

And this is a sample of the Frame class.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container, parent):
```

My problem is, it doesn't work as expected. When it boots up, it shows only StartPage, which is good. And when I try to go to Page1, that's fine as well. But after that I can't go back to StartPage. It would just show empty when I try. One thing concerns me is that when calling f.grid_forget(self), the compiler insist that I give it a argument "self", which I don't need to otherwise. I am wondering if that might be the source of problem.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this loop:

```
for f in self.frames:
    ...
```

In the loop, `f` will be a *class*, not an *instance*. Since `self.frames` is a dictionary with the actual frames being the values, you want to loop over the values:

```
for f in self.frames.values():
    f.grid_forget()
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly where the problem is. Now is fixed and everything works fine.